# Create php key and value array

Tags: php

I am trying to create a key and value array from database record, but the array just getting the final record! Here is a snippet of my code:

```
$cateogiresArr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
  $cateogiresArr["categoryname"] = $row[1];
  $cateogiresArr["description"] = $row[2];
}
header("Content-type:application/json");
$json_categories = json_encode($cateogiresArr);
```

Answer (score 4):

On each iteration add new array with required data to `$cateogiresArr`:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    $cateogiresArr[] = [
        "cateogryname" => $row[1],
        "description" => $row[2],
    ];
}
```

Comment: @PhillipMark Please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the green tick on the left. Also, some spelling corrections: `categoryname`, and `categoriesArr`.